# Model and table name conventions Laravel

Tags: laravel, models

I want to know model and table conventions in Laravel.

I have table users and user_address now I do not want to use

> protected $table = "user_address"

property. Please suggest me the right convention in model or table.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If the name of the model is `UserAddress`, the name of the table should be plural. So it will be `user_addresses`.

Read more about Laravel naming conventions [here](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices#follow-laravel-naming-conventions).

Answer (score 1):

If your model name is User.php then Laravel expects class 'User' to be inside that file. It also expects **users** table for User model (plural form).

Similiarly, If you have a `user_address` model your table should be `user_addresses`