# standard way for naming tables and model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to naming tables in my project, I have a table for tour services.

What is the best naming method for table and model? **camelCase**, **snake_case** or **PascalCase** (upper camelCase)?

is it right for table `'tourServices'` and for model `'TourService'`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Model and table name conventions Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47936761/model-and-table-name-conventions-laravel)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For **table** names: [**Snake Case**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) and the name in plural (if pivot table you could use the singular version of each model and order it alphabetically):

```php
'tour_services' // regular table
'users' // regular table
'roles' // regular table
'role_user' // <-- pivot table
```

For **model** names: [**Pascal Case**](http://wiki.c2.com/?PascalCase) (also in singular)

```php
'TourService'
'User'
'Role'
```

---

Check [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47936780/7117697) that touches this subject. Also, check [this other post](https://medium.com/@pddivine/string-case-styles-camel-pascal-snake-and-kebab-case-981407998841) that talks about case styles.

Comment: @HCK great answer, spot on

Answer (score 0):

You can name the model and let Laravel name the table for you. Tables are mostly named using snake_case, and plural from the model, but you can just run this, and Laravel will do the rest:

```
php artisan make:model TourService -m
```

The `-m` flag creates a migration with the name of the table based on the given model.

But then again, I am not sure that I will go with a `Service` name in the model, maybe just a `Tour` is a good name for the model, I don't know what is the context of the model.